# Image Viewing in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm currently working on a project, and everything has been going well up until I've had to display a grid of images.

I was thinking of using a DrawGrid, but it seems that nothing that displays is selectable or even displaying correctly.

Is there a component I can use that will allow me to display a bunch of images on screen at once, and have them selectable? The rest I can write, its just this one bit which is causing me frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [rkView](http://rmklever.com/?tag=rkview)

Answer (score 0):

TMS has a nice grid.  And you can also use a TListView in thumbnail mode, and use custom drawing to draw whatever you want.